# codeigniter framework upload save on linux mint

Tags: linux, codeigniter, upload

I have below code running on apache on linux mint 64 bit OS. Find that files cannot save on server. Do you know how to solve? add more config or privileges??

```
 $config['file_name'] = basename($imgPath);
            $config['upload_path'] = $upload_dir;  
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp';

            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("image".$i))
```

or

```
$this->image_lib->clear();
                $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config2['source_image'] = $this->upload->upload_path.$this->upload->file_name;
                $config2['new_image'] = $upload_dir_resize.'/'.$thumb_fileName;
                $config2['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config2['width'] = 320;
                $config2['height'] = 320;
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config2);
                if ( !$this->image_lib->resize()){
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting in this, post that error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have `0777` rights on the folder you're saving.

```
if(!file_exists($folderPath))
   mkdir($folderPath, 0777, TRUE);

$config['upload_path']   = $folderPath;
$config['file_name']     = randomStringName();
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|bmp';
$config['max_size']      = '1024'; // 1MB~
$config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

if($this->upload->do_upload('image') == FALSE)
  die('Ups...something went wrong');

$filePath = base_url() . $folderPath . $this->upload->data()['file_name'];
```